# function pageLoad not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, updatepanel, pageload

I have the following code which I want to run when the page first loads and then again when an update panel (asp.net) is run. Therefore I need to use function pageLoad() rather than document.ready.

```
function pageLoad() {
    $(".zoomImage").each( function() {
        $("<img src='"+$(this).attr("src").replace("-thumb.jpg",".jpg")+"' />").appendTo(".howitworksText > div");
    });
};
```

Problem is I can only get this working with document.ready - so therefore not when the updatepanel is run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use scriptmanager

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(a control within update panel, typeof the control in the updatepanel,"soem label", "pageLoad();", true);`

Comment: make sure that the control passed in as the second param is inside the updatepanel as if its not the script wont fire

Answer (score 0):

When using asp.net webforms a scriptmanager must be found at the .aspx file for using the JavaScript function `pageload()`

You can add the scriptManager right below the `<body>` begin tag.

```
<body>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    ...
    ...
</body>
```